# SSH back to AWS Lightsail after UFW enabling

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-lightsail, ufw

I've enabled the UFW service without allowing SSH access before then logging off.

I am now unable to ssh back to the instance.

The steps I have already taken:

- Made a snapshot and create a new instance from it

Comment: Create a new EBS volume from the snapshot. Don't launch as an AMI. attach the EBS volume as a second volume to a different instance. You can then mount it and access the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general point: try to execute a command (**firewall disabling**) while creating a new instance. I was able to do it with the usage of AWS CLI:

```
aws lightsail create-instances-from-snapshot --region eu-central-1 --instance-snapshot-name TEST_SSH_FIX-1591429003 --instance-names TEST_SSH_FIX_2 --availability-zone eu-central-1a --user-data 'sudo service ufw stop' --bundle-id nano_2_0
```

It`s work.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a snapshot and use it to create another new instance, and add `sudo service ufw stop` to the launch script.

[image]

[image]