# Unable to connect via SSH to AWS Lightsail instance created from snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I am having the exact same problem, I tried:

1. From the UI:
   1.1. Create instance from automatic snapshot.
   1.2. Create instance from manually created snapshot.
2. From the CLI:
   2.1. Create instance from manual snapshot also trying to disable the firewall like this answer: [SSH back to AWS Lightsail after UFW enabling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181754/ssh-back-to-aws-lightsail-after-ufw-enabling)
3. Creating different static IPs for the new instance.
4. Using different SSH key/pairs (default & new) in instance creation.
5. Recreating firewall rules from the UI.
6. Rebooting the instance.

The result of `aws lightsail get-instances` is:

```
{
  "name": "Wordpress-Spain",
   ...
   "ports": [
     {
      "fromPort": 22,
      "toPort": 22,
      "protocol": "tcp",
       "accessFrom": "Anywhere (0.0.0.0/0)",
       "accessType": "public",
       "commonName": "",
       "accessDirection": "inbound",
       "cidrs": [
         "0.0.0.0/0"
       ],
     },
  ...  }
```

while nmap throws:

```
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  closed ssh
80/tcp  open   http
443/tcp open   https
```

According to the Lightsail UI & AWS CLI everything is ok, but I consi

> An error occurred and we were unable to connect or stay connected to your instance. If this instance has just started up, try again in a minute or two.
> UPSTREAM_NOT_FOUND [519]

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Launched an **Amazon Linux 2 instance** in Amazon Lightsail
- **Connected via SSH** and created a file on the instance (for testing purposes)
- Created a **Manual Snapshot** of the instance
- Launched a **new instance** from the Snapshot (with all default settings)
- Connected to the new instance via SSH (clicking on the SSH icon in the console)
- Displayed the contents of the test file -- it matched!

The above steps were all done with default settings. It worked fine for me!

I then repeated the above using a **WordPress blueprint**. I was able to login to the second instance just fine.

So, it doesn't look like a Lightsail problem. It likely has to do with something that has been changed/configured on the operating system.